# Robot Framework: Rest call gives "unicode object has no attribute copy" error

Tags: robotframework

Below error occurring on my code

```
${resp}=  Post Request  sw3  https://sw3-   test.test1.com/api/v1/test1/patients
\  ...  Content-Type:application/json
\  ...  Authorization:authkey02    Accept=application/json
```

Error as follows

```
KEYWORD ${resp} = RequestsLibrary . Post Request sw3, https://sw3-test.test1.com/api/v1/test1/patients, Content-Type:application/json, Authorization:authkey02, Accept=application/json
Documentation:  
Send a POST request on the session object found using the
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170315 12:08:21.283 / 20170315 12:08:21.285 / 00:00:00.002
12:08:21.283    TRACE   Arguments: [ 'sw3' | 'https://sw3-test.test1.com/api/v1/test1/patients' | 'Content-Type:application/json' | 'Authorization:authkey02' | 'Accept=application/json' ] 
12:08:21.284    FAIL    AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

This works ok if i do not use the third line of code - what gives?

Comment: Have you tried using &{resp} instead of ${resp}?

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try like passing those `key:value` pairs as a dictionary *Header* variable.

```
&{Header}=   Content-Type:application/json    Authorization:authkey02 
   Accept=application/json


${resp} = RequestsLibrary.Post Request  sw3   https://sw3-test.test1.com/api/v1/test1/patients    headers=${Header}
```